Getting heap corruption detected error while unallocating memory
I am getting error of heap corruption detected when I try to deallocate memory! This is my code
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char *reverse(char *arr, int size) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = size-1; i > size/2; i--) {
        char temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
        j++;
    }
    return arr;
}
void display(char* arr, int size) {
    for (int i = 0;  arr[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}
int main() {
    int size;
    cout << "Enter the size of string." << endl;
    cin >> size;
    char* sentence = new char[size];
    cout << "Enter sentence: ";
    cin >> sentence;
    char *arr_ay = reverse(sentence, size);
    display(arr_ay, size);
    delete[] sentence;
    return 0;
}

Please explain me what is this error and how to tackle this one!
I really don't know what is heap corruption detected error and how to tackle this! Please guide me.

you are missing the byte required for the null terminator, \0, your array needs to have size+1 size.

For one thing a C style string requires an extra byte for the nul terminator, so new char[size + 1];. But on the other hand, don't you think your program would be better if it could work out the length of the string for itself, from the characters actually entered? That might seem difficult to you, but in C++ the work has already been done. Use std::string instead of character arrays for strings.

@سید نعمان In any case the function reverse is wrong. It will not reverse an array for size equal to 2.

@سید نعمان Pay attention to that this statement cin >> sentence; is unsafe. You need to use another input function for character arrays.

cin >> sentence; should be named cin >> word; because it will only read 1 word stopping on the first whitespace character.

@john thank you but i am not supposed to use std:: string in this code, as instructed by my mentor. By using your solution, my code is working fine.
@VladfromMoscow you are right. I was trying just to reduce the iterations; however, it is working fine when I put 'j' as a terminating condition for 'i' in the loop!

@سیدنعمان Your "mentor" sucks.

@سیدنعمان Your mentor has the wrong idea about learning C++. You should learn C++ techniques (like std::string) before you learn about C techniques (like allocating memory for strings). Too often it is done the other way around. The result is that to become a good C++ pogrammer you will have to unlearn all the C programming techniques you have been taught.

Show your teacher this Stop teaching "C" and the C++ core guidelines. we stopped coding like this in C++ at least since 2011 (possibly even since 1998) and we avoid explicit calls to new/delete as much as we can. Nowadays if you want to ouput the reverse of text we use something like std::string string{"Hello"}; for(const char c : string | std::views::reverse) { std::cout << c; };.

And if you are not allowed to use std::string at least make a string class that can handle all the new/deletes, reversing etc.

Why not just accept that OP has an assignment to do the way he has been instructed to do it and help him with that? All the should stuff is irrelevant to actually helping him.

C-String Input
To read a C-string using std::cin, use the .get() member function.
int main()
{
    char sentence[100];
    std::cout << "sentence? ";
    std::cin.get( sentence, sizeof(sentence) );

Reverse
You are on the right track, but your termination condition could use a little help. If all you have is i and j, but if you did not know the original size, how would you know when to stop swapping?
Remember, j is 0, 1, ...
And i is (for example) 17, 16, ...
Visually:
0, 1, 2, ...    ... 15, 16, 17
j -->                    <-- i

P.S.
You can get the actual size of the input string without having to ask the user with strlen():
#include <cstring>

    reverse( sentence, strlen(sentence) );

